# Keep memory item in RAM, disallow it from being paged to disk

Tags: c++, c, memory, paging, ram

Is there anyway to tell the computer to keep an item in ram or at least to try its hardest to keep it from being paged to disk? I would like to be able to do this to ensure that my section of memory will never have to go to disk to fetch its information as I know it is something that will need to be fetched almost instantly  but may not be fetched frequently

This is with linux. Though I would be interested in other platforms if you have an answer for those as well

Comment: Do you want that item to be in ram during the whole program lifecycle ?

Comment: what OS/configuration/etc?

Comment: I wonder if you could do occasional random accesses to keep it around.  How big is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's O/S specific, however...

In POSIX world you use [mlock and mlockall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) to indicate that the data must be kept in RAM and not paged out. You may require serious user privileges for this.

Watch out for Linuxes default [overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html) policy though. If you want to be sure you actually have the memory you mallocated make sure you touch it all before you lock it and assume it's all in RAM.

Depending on why you really care about this you may even be in the position to remove swap altogether. Depending where your system is swapping to (DMA, PIO etc.) this might be your only assurance of performance, regardless of what you do in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off paging within OS. At program level paging is mostly opaque. You can compile your program with 64 bit to get you extra addressable memory.

Comment: Just because its addressable doesn't mean there is RAM there... I need to ensure it stays in RAM not just be guessing that it is

Comment: This will "work" but it is not advisable. First, it will not entirely avoid page faults. Pages are still moved out of your working set into the free pool as you exceed your quota (and moved back when they fault). They're not written to and read from disk at least, though. This works fine as long as physical > virtual. Once that's no longer true, it goes _BOOOOOOM!_ -- which may, depending on the OS and OS version, mean that the offending process is killed, or a _random_ process is killed, or the whole system hangs.

Answer (score -1):

The proper call is `madvise(p, sizeof(*p), MADV_WILLNEED)`. That tells Linux that you **will  need** `*p` soon. That will even cause Linux to unpage it, if it accidentily happened to be paged.

Unlike `mlock`, this call can be done without serious user privileges.